# Equivalent command for 'cllsnode' in RHEL server

Tags: linux, unix, rhel

I am migrating server from AIX to RHEL. As cllsnode is not working in RHEL. Please someone help me with equivalent command for 'cllsnode'

About the command:

```
It is used to list a node centric overview of the hacmp configuration.
```

Comment: You sure you have such High Availability Cluster in your new x86_64/RedHat platform?

Comment: I am not sure about it @LorinczyZsigmond

Comment: Is it RHEL on Power (in LPAR)?

Comment: You should write a script that gives the expected output.